# How to remove multiple shipping addresses in Magento community?

Tags: magento, php

I'm preparing to launch  a ordering site(Platform: Magento-Community). I would like to hide or remove the edit/add new address from the checkout page. Can you please advice.

Thank you in advance,
Illes

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GO to `app/design/frontend/[theme_package]/[theme]/template/persistent/checkout/onepage`
Open `billing.phtml` file approx line no 188 you will find `ship to different address`
Comment that line.
 Your Problem is solved.
And
Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage` and copy the file `Abstract.php` then create the directory structure as `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage` and paste the file. Then approx line number 141 you can find this `$select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));` comment this line using '//code' and save the file.

Comment: > Blockquote<li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
        </li>> Blockquote

Comment: yes comment this. It will work as you wanted in those images for illustration.

Comment: I just did it as you mentioned, but its still displaying multiple addresses option.<!--<li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
        </li>-->

Comment: it worked in my case. clear the cache and reindex the data then check again.

Comment: Cache, reindex are done, but its still the same. Multiple addresses option remained.

Comment: I just checked with the location with the "Debug" and I think is the same as your: frontend/base/default/template/username/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml. Also after this I cleared the cache internet browser, magento, reindex too. But nothing changed.

Comment: delete the line and try

Comment: just add <?php echo 'test'; ?>  and check if is it displaying.

Comment: Make sure you are not modifying another package/theme file. Modify the current working theme file only.

Comment: Yes, we're in the right page. see src: http://www.thebodyshop.ie/multiple-shipping-addresses/

Comment: ok so you dont want to display add new address in the 'dropdown list' or you dont want to display ship to different address 'radio' box?

Comment: I don't want provide an option to change different shipping address. So what we have on the shipping tab is "dropdown: New Address"<- I need this to be hidden. But, just below it "Radio button(default): Ship to this address can be remain".

Comment: ok then go to app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage and copy the file Abstract.php then create the directory structure as app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage and paste the file. Then approx line number 141 you can find this $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address')); comment this line using '//code' and save the file.....

Comment: I made the changes, and carried out cache & reindexing. And I think its done now! Is this would be working without the new directory?

Comment: it will also work when directly changing in the source directory however when there is any update, your changes will be vanished so it is always better no to touch any files in "app/code/core" so always do in "app/code/local". By the way is it working now?

Comment: I understood, and keep in mind! Yes, its working now, super how great your experience and you're very helpful. I wish I could ask one more advice. Many thanks again!

Comment: See above the new screen shot(under the original first question).

Comment: Would you have any idea how to make the add to cart process easier? I would like to split the "DISCOVER" button, just under each product, and put there an option as "ADD TO CART" (see above image in the original question). I found one extension but I never integrated any extension myself. Also you may have a better idea, or suggestion?

Comment: Note: The "/PACK" tag is already implemented, just the image were created last week...

Comment: sorry i didn't get you question. How exactly you wanted to make it?

Comment: The main idea is to make the "ADD TO CART" process quicker. Right now is: landing on category page/sub category/discover product/product page(where the item can be add to cart). I would like to make this like: /sub category/discover product& add to cart/. So it would be one steps less, quicker process. Is do you know any good extension/plug in to do this? If so would you be able to advice how to integrated?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the "Checkout with Multiple Addresses" option on your Magento website. Here's how:
Login to your Magento site's Admin Panel:

```
Go to System==> Configuration ==> Shipping Settings 
(Go to on the left menu under Sales section)
==>Options Tab ==>Set "Allow Shipping to multiple addresses" to "No"

==>Save Config
```

If you do not see any changes make sure the Magento Cache is cleared
Go to System and select Cache Management
Refresh the cache and check your site again.
Good luck with Magento settings.